# Assign an ID based on keywords present in Tweets

Tags: r, nlp, uniqueidentifier

I have extracted Tweets by feeding in 44 different keywords, and the output is in a file which consists of 400k tweets in total. The output file has tweets that contain the relevant keywords. How could I create a separate ID column which contains the keyword present in that tweet?

Eg: The tweet is:

> Andhra Pradesh is the highest state with crimes against women

the keyword here is "crimes against women"

I would like to create a column that assigns the keyword "crimes against women" to the tweet, a sort of ID column to be precise.

```
#input column 1
Tweet<-("Andhra Pradesh is the highest state with crimes against women")

#expected output column 2 beside the Tweet column
Keyword<-("crimes against women")
```

Edit: I do not want to extract any part of the tweet, I just want to be able to assign to the tweet, in a new column, the keyword it contains so it will help me segregate the tweets based on this keyword.

Comment: Do you have a list of the keywords that you want to extract from the tweets?

Comment: Yes, I have the list of the keywords- 44 to be exact. I used the keywords to extract the tweets in the first place.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought that is what you were looking for. I misread. Let me re-open your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform this analysis with the `stringr` package, however, I don't think you need to use `sapply`.

Consider the following keyword list and table with tweets:

```
keyword_list <- c("crimes against women", "downloading tweets", "r analysis")

tweets <- data.frame(
  tweet = c("Andhra Pradesh is the highest state with crimes against women",
            "I am downloading tweets",
            "I love r analysis",
            "downloading tweets helps with my r analysis")
)
```

First, you want to combine your keywords into one regular expression that searches for any of the strings.

```
keyword_pattern <- paste0(
  "(",
  paste0(keyword_list, collapse = "|"),
  ")"
)

keyword_pattern
#> [1] "(crimes against women|downloading tweets|r analysis)"
```

Finally, we can add a column to the data frame that extracts the keyword from the tweet.

```
tweets$keyword <- str_extract(tweets$tweet, keyword_pattern)

> tweets
#>                                                           tweet              keyword
#> 1 Andhra Pradesh is the highest state with crimes against women crimes against women
#> 2                                       I am downloading tweets   downloading tweets
#> 3                                             I love r analysis           r analysis
#> 4                   downloading tweets helps with my r analysis   downloading tweets
```

As the final example illustrates, you need to think about what you want to do when a tweet contains multiple keywords. In this case, the keyword returned is simply the first one found in the tweet. However, you can also use `str_extract_all` to return ALL keywords found in the tweet.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `stringr` which is very handy for string operations and simply use `str_extract`, i.e.

```
str_extract(Tweet, Keyword)
#[1] "crimes against women"
```

For multiple keywords and multiple strings you need to apply, i.e.

```
Keyword <- c("crimes against women", "something")
Tweet <- c("Andhra Pradesh is the highest state with crimes against women", 
           "another string with something else")

sapply(Tweet, function(i)str_extract(i, paste(Keyword, collapse = '|')))

#    Andhra Pradesh is the highest state with crimes against women                            another string with something else 
#                                           "crimes against women"                                                   "something"
```